# Problems with errors.add and valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have to import big CSV tables. My code search for existing objects in database otherwise i create a new instance.

My wish is to add custom error messages if it is necessary after that i have to validate my model.

Here my code example:

```
def customer_validate
  p = Customer.new(customer_params)
  p.errors.add(:name, "here my error message")
  p.valid?
  return p
end
```

Problem:
All errors get lost after *p.valid?* How can i combine custom error messages and valid? messages?

Comment: Can you past code of your model?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. When you run `valid?` all the existing errors are cleared. There are a few possible workarounds.

One simple possibility is to toggle the order.

```
def customer_validate
  c = Customer.new(customer_params)
  c.valid?
  c.errors.add(:name, "here my error message")
  c
end
```

and you can check whether the customer is valid using

```
customer = customer_validate
customer.errors.any?
```

Another approach would be to attach the errors to a temporary customer object, run `valid?` on your primary object and then merge the two error lists.

As a side note, do not name the variables `p` since `p` is a method in Ruby, you will end up shadowing it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use after_validation like below.

```
  after_validation do
    errors.add(:name, 'abc')
  end
```